# Disabled div content using css

Tags: css

```
<div class="children"> Sachin </div>
<div class="children"> Moron</div>
<div class="children"> Peter </div>
```

is it possible to apply color to div with specfic content like below

If div content is sachin then i need to disabled it, other wise it will enable

```
.children sachin {
    cursor: not-allowed;
  opacity: 0.5;
  
  }
```

Comment: Not without using JavaScript in some way, CSS can't select elements based on the contents.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it if you are able to use [data attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes).

```css
.children[data-name="Sachin"] {
  opacity: 0.5;
  cursor: not-allowed;
}
```

```html
<div class="children" data-name="Sachin">Sachin</div>
<div class="children" data-name="Moron">Moron</div>
<div class="children" data-name="Peter">Peter</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add a `disabled` class to the divs you want to disable.

```html
<div class="children disabled"> Sachin </div>
<div class="children"> Moron </div>
<div class="children"> Peter </div>
```

```
.children.disabled {
  opacity: 0.5;
  cursor: not-allowed;
}
```

Using the `disabled` html attibute is also possible:

```html
<div class="children" disabled> Sachin </div>
<div class="children"> Moron </div>
<div class="children"> Peter </div>
```